# How can I change the CSS style using Typescript method in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

Using the below code I hide the div tag successfully.

Html file

```
  <mat-toolbar style="position: fixed;"  *ngIf="div1"  >
    <mat-toolbar-row>
      <div class="input-group has-search">
        <input class="form-control py-2 rounded-pill mr-1 pr-5"  placeholder="Search">
      </div>
    </mat-toolbar-row>
    </mat-toolbar>

  <button (click)="home()></button>
```

Ts file

```
 div1:boolean=true;

    home()
      {
        this.div1=false;
     }
```

But I can see a space. Because of toolbar position is fixed. How I change the toolbar position in the "home()" method. (Ex:  position: fixed to relative)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this several different ways, you can use [ngStyle] which will set all the styles.  You can use [class.classname]="true/false" or like I have here just set the style for position directly.

However the *ngIf should completely remove the element, so your styling issue you are seeing could be unrelated.

```
  <mat-toolbar [style.position]="div1 ? 'fixed' : 'static'" *ngIf="div1"  >
     <mat-toolbar-row>
        <div class="input-group has-search">
           <input class="form-control py-2 rounded-pill mr-1 pr-5" placeholder="Search">
         </div>
      </mat-toolbar-row>
   </mat-toolbar>

   <button (click)="home()></button>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can employ `ngStyle` property for this, something like:

```html
 
<mat-toolbar [ngStyle]="{'position': div1 ? 'fixed' : 'static' }" *ngIf="div1"  >
    <mat-toolbar-row>
      <div class="input-group has-search">
        <input class="form-control py-2 rounded-pill mr-1 pr-5"  placeholder="Search">
      </div>
    </mat-toolbar-row>
    </mat-toolbar>

  <button (click)="home()></button>
<mat-toolbar>
```